# Is it possible to make a website responsive after a user has given a permission

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a responsive website. The problem is that I don't want the website to be responsive to start acting responsive until the user has given a permission to browse the responsive website.

When a user has viewed the website on a tablet, a massage or link will show asking the user to change to responsive[I can do this part]

I believe that this can be done using `jQuery` and `CSS`. But i'm not sure that is a good approach. I need some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you could put all responsive css in a responsive css file, then simply ask your user if it wants responsive.

if you user says yes, then append the css to the document simply by adding the ref line, browser will reinterpret the included css document

```
<a onclick="makeresponsive()"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeresponsive()
{   
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css" type="text/css" />');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add your responsive CSS file (i.e. the one containing all the `@media` queries) after the user has approved:

```
if (confirm('Make responsive?')) {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css" type="text/css" />');
}
```

Generally speaking, there's no real need to ask the user to make the site responsive. If you've figured out the target device properly, just apply the styling.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way might be to prefix all your responsive styles with a `body.class` selector, eg. `body.responsive`. So

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

becomes

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body.responsive .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

If the user wants the site to be responsive, you add the `responsive` class to the body element, and your styles come into effect.

```
$('body').addClass('responsive')
```